# Blazor Time Localisation

Tags: time, blazor-server-side

Hi i am in trouble with time, I want to display the time and update it in realtime
I already installed "Install-Package Blazored.Localisation"
below is the sample code

```
string currentLocalTime = "";

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender) // Remove the firstRender check if you want the current local time displayed to continuously update.
    {   // Leave the above firstRender check in place to ensure that the call to StateHasChanged() does not trigger an endless update loop.
        var browserDateTime = await browserDateTimeProvider.GetInstance();
        currentLocalTime = browserDateTime.Now.ToString();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but your problem is localization or display time continously ?
Your code simply display the time "one-shot" when your page is rendered

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you can remove first render check if you want to continuously update.
Just remove If statement.

```
string currentLocalTime = "";

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
      var browserDateTime = await browserDateTimeProvider.GetInstance();
      currentLocalTime = browserDateTime.Now.ToString();
      StateHasChanged();
}
```